# undefined method `file_import' for DumpDate rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

In controller:

```
def import
@dump_date = DumpDate.find(params[:dump_date_id])
file_name = params[:path]
@dump_date.delay.file_import(file_name)
....
end
```

In model `DumpDate`:

```
class DumpDate < ActiveRecord::Base
require 'rake'
worker = Delayed::Worker.new # or add options
worker.start

def file_import(file_name) 
Rake::Task["import_dump_file:fake_people"].execute :message=>    file_name         
end
end
```

In my application i am using gem `delayed_job_active_record`.When running `rake jobs:work` in the terminal it works fine.But when i am running it in  the development mode i am getting error in the table `delayed_job` like `undefined method file_import for DumpDate`.

I have lost 2 days for getting some solution, no luck yet! Please help me out!

Comment: Please fix formatting of your source code.

Comment: Hey @Uday kumar das! Did you manage to solve your issue?

Comment: No @EugZol, i have not managed to fix this issue.